# I have a long list of dataframe and want to convert each to numpy array X1,X2,X3 given pandas dataframes df1,df2,df3 in python using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a long list of pandas dataframes. The need for me is to get numpy array X1 for dataframe df1, numpy array X2 for dataframe df2, numpy array X3 for dataframe df3 without doing it one after the other.
i.e

```
X1=df1.values
X2=df2.values
X3=df3.values
```

Using for loops comes to mind. Anyone can help with this?
example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,3],'color':['Red','Green','Blue'],'symbol':['R','G','B']}

                ,columns=['number','color','symbol'])

df2=pd.DataFrame({'number':[4,5,6],'color':['Black','Yellow','Orange'],'symbol':['B','Y','O']}

                ,columns=['number','color','symbol'])

df3=pd.DataFrame({'number':[7,8,9],'color':['Purple','White','Violet'],'symbol':['P','W','V']}

                ,columns=['number','color','symbol'])
```

[image: example dataframe df1]

[image: example output numpy array X1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,3],'color':['Red','Green','Blue'],'symbol':['R','G','B']}

                ,columns=['number','color','symbol'])

df2=pd.DataFrame({'number':[4,5,6],'color':['Black','Yellow','Orange'],'symbol':['B','Y','O']}

                ,columns=['number','color','symbol'])

df3=pd.DataFrame({'number':[7,8,9],'color':['Purple','White','Violet'],'symbol':['P','W','V']}

                ,columns=['number','color','symbol'])

for i in range(1,4):
    globals()["X" + str(i)] = np.array(globals()["df" + str(i)])
```

Comment: This works for the question though but my dataframes do not follow a specific naming convention. What if df1 is oslo, df2 is tokyo and df3 is moscow and I want to return numpy arrays of X_oslo, X_tokyo and X_moscow respectively?

Comment: You can create a list of names: names = ["oslo", "tokyo", "moscow"], then loop it using for name in names: globals()["X_" + name] = np.array(globals()[name])

Comment: If this worked fine for you, may I ask you to validate the answer as correct?